# Javascript DOM Document createElement from tag source

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, document

Is there a way to create a new element in a Document object from the tag source? Essentially what I'd like to do is something to effect of:

```
myDocument.createElement('<sometag attr="lol">');
```

Answer (score 2):

No, native DOM API for `.createElement` doesn't support that syntax. You need to create the plain Element and set any property either directly on the object

```
newElem.attr = "lol";
```

or (better), use `.setAttribute()`

```
newElem.setAttribute( 'attr', 'lol' );
```

<strike>What you "could" do is do create a `documentFragment`, then use `.innerHTML` to write that string into that fragment and finally `.append` its contents to its target destination.</strike>

Comment: It looks like `setAttribute()` [is slower than](http://jsperf.com/setattribute-vs-attr) `.attr` :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: very possible. But the caveat is that afaik this syntax is nowhere described in any spec up to this point. So its pretty vague coding style. Anyway it seems almost all browser support that syntax anyway "somehow". So, its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

well, use innerHTML instead of trying to hack dom manipulation for this kind of thing.

To do so, create a valid node with dom if you want (or get it via getElementById), then set innerHTML of this node with your code

Answer (score 0):

The innerHTML property works here - but it's a tad bit difficult to place the thing where you want it sometimes. For example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png'/>";
```

In my humble opinion, it's a heck of a lot easier to use jQuery to handle it for you, as it comes with all of the jQuery methods already attached.

```
var div = $("<div class='blah'><img src='http://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png'/></div>");
div.find('img').hide();
div.appendTo('body');
div.find('img').fadeIn();
```